# Want to make Node Red on Raspberry Pi detected Data from Arduino and React to it but unsure how to do so?

Tags: node.js, arduino, raspberry-pi, node-red

I recently made a sensor that can correctly display the distances on the Serial Monitor on the Arduino, it would continuously display the distance as I would move my hand up/down the sensor. Thing is though, I intended on connecting this to a Pi (mine being Pi 3B+), use Node Red and basically have it detect that whenever the distance was "20cm" for example, then it would go straight to a YouTube video and play it. I tried researching all over the net to see if such had been done before, but to no avail as I found content much different than what I tried to pull off with Node Red and my Arduino.

I did try on my end to set up a **function** on Node Red to my Arduino, using a conditional statement to detect something and print something else out.

**Overview of what I tried to do on Node Red**

[image: Overview of what I tried to do]
As you can see, there was not much to add as I was initially trying to test the conditional statement I made, making it output something on the debug screen using the code below:

**Contents of the function created**

```
var newMsg = {payload:msg.payload.toString()}:
if (newMsg == 'Distance: 20cm') {
    newMsg = 'Distance is 20, nice'
    return newMsg;
}
return newMsg;
```

Even with the little test I created to return a message to the debug did not work, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68986873/edit) explain what you think that function node does, because trying to compare an Object to a String is not going to do what you think it will.

Comment: Alright will do

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be creating new message objects as a rule, this breaks flows that use things like `http-in`/`http-response` nodes that require the original message to pass from start to end.

Second, you can't compare an Object to a String and get anything meaningful. The function node probably should looks something like the following:

```
if (msg.payload === "Distance: 20") {
    msg.payload = "Distance is 20cm, nice"
    return msg;
}
```

Third, the input message appears to be terminated with a new line character so the test should probably be:

```
if (msg.payload === "Distance: 20\n") {
```